# How to set up remote graphical sessions on CentOs?

Tags: linux, desktop, vnc, session, remote-management

Trying to set up a Centos 6 server configuration where we can automate the running of an application that uses Selenium.  In this case, ideally, we should be able to:

1. Create a graphical session (which should remain open for at least 30 minutes).
2. Run an application that will continue running while the session is active.
3. Have that application, using Selenium, run automated website tests.

What sort of installation / configuration do I need to do this?  I've already set up `gdm` and  a `vnc` server to test it out. I am at a loss, however, on what to do next.

Comment: This looks very familiar :)  Have you withdrawn your other question re Selenium and a browser running on a server?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  This is my first question on this forum and definitely the only one regarding this that I have asked.

Comment: In that case my apologies. I partook in a discussion a few days ago with exactly the same objective. Centos server, remote desktop, to run Selenium. The question and my answer and comments with it disappeared. I assumed it was the same person asking.

Comment: Nope, I actually just opened this account to ask this question.  No apologies necessary, though.  In fact, if you have some information that could help out, I'd really appreciate it :)